# vba find doesnt work on merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

Good day, My find fuction works find with no merged cells but doesnt work with merged cells in column A. It throws a Run-time error '91', object variable or With block variable not set.

```
Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
, "Please select file")
If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)


With wb2.Sheets(1)
  firstrow = .Range("A:A").find(what:="Total", after:=.Range("A1")).Row + 1
End With
```

Comment: Does it not work when the thing to be found is in the merged cell?

Comment: no it doesnt, if i take the cells off merged then it does work perfectly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following should solve that issue for you:

```
With wb2.Sheets(1)
   firstrow = .Range("A:A").find(what:="Total", after:=.Range("A1")).MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Row + 1
End With
```

Comment: I should add, "Total" is always in a merged cell, there are cells before it that are not mergered and some that are in different sizes